# How to fix path error when a react build application is deployed in apache tomcat

Tags: reactjs, tomcat

I have developed a react application and created a production build using "npm run build". When I put this build files in webapps folder(named ldap) of apache tomcat and start the server and go to "http://localhost:8080/ldap/" this link it is showing 404 errors for all static files.

I looked in the network tab and saw that all my static files are served from http://localhost:8080/static/css/main.4e0cec6e.chunk.css it is missing "ldap" part in the link(http://localhost:8080/ldap/static/css/main.4e0cec6e.chunk.css)

Is there a way to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are mounting your React app in a subdirectory, you need to tackle a couple of things.

The first would be to set the basename prop in your router, this tells your React app that it will be mounted in a subdirectory.

```
<Router basename={'/your-directory'}>
  <Route path='/' component={SomeComponent} />
</Router>
```

The next thing you need to do is to set the homepage parameter in your `package.json` file. You set the full URL of your app.

`"homepage": "https://yourapp.com/your-directory"`

And the third and final thing you need to do is update your links and routes.

Example for Route:

```
<Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} component={HomeComponent} />
<Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/other-dir`} component={SomeOtherComponent} />
```

Example for Link:

```
<Link to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/other-dir`}>Link to /other-dir</Link>
```

Comment: @BojonIvanac thank you. I tried what you have suggested, I have followed the instruction and build the app it was able to catch the proper path, but nothing was displaying. After some adjustment( like I removed the use of "process.env.PUBLIC_URL") and re-building and deployed in apache tomcat I was able to get the result.

Comment: @sumeeth Perfect, glad it helped, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: I tried this but its not  working